# Can't choose Plane Track in Plane Track Deform node while compositing

Tags: compositing-nodes, tracking

I created 4 markers and used them to 'Create Plane Track'. This worked fine.

Then, in the compositor, I added a 'Plane Track Deform' node, selected an image for it, and chose 'Camera'. Clicking on the plane track dropdown, I don't see my plane track. The dropdown is empty.

What am I missing? I looked at tutorials, they all just pick the plane track from the dropdown, and mine is empty. Could it be that the plane track is not associated with the camera?

For the record, here's the plane track (in the motion tracking layout):
[image]

Then, the plane track doesn't show in the compositor:
[image]

Any idea what I'm missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a plane track, just select the solve tab, then plane drop down and lastly create plane track. you should now be able to select the plane track compositing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A plane track is attached to the clip that you track the markers in.

The plane track node has a clip name starting with `Logo.` while the tracking is done with `fr0001`. The clip for the plane track mask is the one you tracked while the image input socket is the image that will be distorted over the clip.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the footage from the dropdown menu on the left instead of finding it in the file browser. Then, you'll be able to select the camera and then the plane track.

[image]