# How can I track a moving board and superimpose a video on top of it?

Tags: video, tracking, 2d

You know Captain Disillusion? "The World's Greatest Blenderer"?
Well, he does this effect all the time in his videos; Adding videos on top of a board he's holding, to make it seem like he's holding one large, suspiciously bezel-less, screen.

[image: SUSPICIOUS BEZELS INDEED!!]

Now, I'd like to emulate that in my video project.
This MUST be a simple process, easier than adding a 3D object to a scene, since it's simply tracking a 2D plane and superimposing a 2D layer on top.
But I just can't figure out HOW I would look this up!
"Chroma keying" just turns up tutorials of how to remove backgrounds from videos (Done that before), and other keywords didn't help.

So, how can I do this? And, do I need a green board for this, or would a white board with dots on it be better? And importantly, how would I go about masking the video (to compensate for fingers, etc)? Would it be better to use Adobe After Effects, since I have that in hand?

Thank you guys for the help!
It would be amazing to be able to make this effect work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is called **Plane Tracking**. The idea is that you associate 4 trackers to the vertices of a plane or an image.

Track the elements and select Create Plane Track.
[image]

In the compositor you use the tracking information to deform an image.

For more detail read the following links:

[Can't choose Plane Track in Plane Track Deform node while compositing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79390/cant-choose-plane-track-in-plane-track-deform-node-while-compositing)

[Is it possible to take a mask clip and 'connect' it to a specific point on a moving object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23865/is-it-possible-to-take-a-mask-clip-and-connect-it-to-a-specific-point-on-a-mov/23902#23902)

And yes, it would be easier to use a green (or blue) screen on the card you film, otherwise you will need to create masks over the fingers and other elements that occlude the card. Such process is called **rotoscoping**, it is more complicated and tedious than dealing with green screen.

Comment: I was JUST trying out masking.. It is a real big pain. Could you please tell me more about using green screens to add plane trackers? I have no idea how to start off, and every tutorial I see just uses trackers and masks.. I would REALLY appreciate it if you can tell me, that would make the process so much easier! Thank you for the help!

Comment: which I have done. Thank you for the helpful answer!